# Custom html forms in django?

Tags: python, html, django, python-2.7, django-forms

I am a beginner in python and django programming, i have a question that already have been asked in stackoverflow and many forums, but i couldnt solve my own.

this exactly my situation:

this the code in my app html page:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}            
    {{ form.as_p }} 
    <footer>
        <button type="submit" class="button">Confirmer</button>
    </footer>    
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

but in my base.html i have already this form and this classes:

```
<form action="" class="sky-form">
    <section>
        <label class="input">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Confirmation">
                <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right">Retaper votre mot de passe</b>
        </label>
    </section>
.
.
.
.
</form>
```

where should i put `{% block content %}` and `{% endblock %}` in my base.html!!!!!!

i've also followed the tutorial from the official docs, but it did,'t work out for me

i'm sorry if my question seem silly!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` wherever you want that block of content to appear in your base.html.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the form in your base.html.

In your base.html you should have something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...put your css and metatags here....
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

Then in your app html templates you just include.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
..... Place form code here!.....
{% endblock %}
```

Now whenever you want to display code in the body of your html you can just use `{% block content %}` and not have to re-write the base.html code over and over! Just as the code says you are *extending* the base template.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions.